# Complex Functions: Integrability

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definition

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space with measure $\lambda$.

Denote the space of simple functions by:
$$\mathcal{S}:=\{s:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}:s=\sum_{k=1}^{K<\infty}s_k\chi_{A_k:\lambda(A_k)<\infty}\}$$

Denote the positive and negative part of the real and imaginary part by:
$$f=\Re_+f-\Re_-f+i\Im_+f-i\Im_-f=:\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha f_\alpha$$

Define for positive functions:
$$\int fd\lambda:=\sup_{s\in\mathcal{S}:s\leq f}\int sd\lambda\quad(f\geq 0)$$
and for complex functions:
$$\int fd\lambda:=\sum_{\alpha=1\ldots3}i^\alpha\int f_\alpha d\alpha$$
as long as all terms of the sum are finite.

*(Note, measurability is not required here!)*

Then a direct consequence is:
$$|\int fd\lambda|\leq\int|f|d\lambda$$
which shows that the a suitable integrability condition will be:
$$\int|f|d\lambda<\infty\implies\int f_\alpha d\lambda<\infty\quad(\alpha=0\ldots3)$$

Now, is it possible for the converse to actually fail:
$$\int|f|d\lambda<\infty\impliedby\int f_\alpha d\lambda<\infty\quad(\alpha=0\ldots3)$$
and what would be a demonstrative example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploiting the estimates:
$$f_\alpha\leq|f|$$
$$|f|\leq\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}f_\alpha$$
one has by additivity and monotonicity of the integral:
$$\int f_\alpha d\lambda\leq\int|f|d\lambda$$
$$\int|f|d\lambda\leq\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}\int f_\alpha d\lambda$$

Concluding that:
$$f\in L(\lambda)\iff f_\alpha\in L(\lambda)\quad(\alpha=0\ldots3)$$